# Session in PassportJS using ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am doing a login page with passportjs and expressjs, everything looks ok on the form but when I tried to use the session I get an error and the page is not render. can someone give a little hint?

App.js

```
// Routes
var viewRoute  = require('./routes/view'),
    apiRoute   = require('./routes/api'),
    loginRoute = require('./routes/login'),
    appRoute   = require('./routes/main');

app.use('/',viewRoute);
app.use('/api',apiRoute);
app.use('/app',appRoute);

app.use('/login',loginRoute);
app.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local',{

        failureRedirect: '/',
        successRedirect: '/app'
    }));
```

my Routes/Main.js

```
var express = require('express');



module.exports = (function(){

    'use strict';

    var appRoute = express.Router();

    appRoute.get('/', function(req, res) {

        if (req.session.passport.user === undefined) {

                res.redirect('/login');
        }
        else { res.render('index'); }
    });

    return appRoute;

})();
```

I'm new with nodejs and I couldn't find anything related. Usually the example is just one single app.js

Answer (score 1):

`res.render` uses templating to render a page.  It doesn't look like you set up a templating engine.  The express website provides a brief intro on how to do this (http://expressjs.com/guide/using-template-engines.html).  If you wish to not use a template, you should use another method such as `res.send`.

Comment: Thanks @Mark I will try to take a look on the link although my issue is with the **req.session.passport.user**, that is the thing node does not recognize